# getelementbyid in external js not working for a asp.net-customcontrol

Tags: javascript, external, getelementbyid, asp.net-customcontrol

have a custom control with a button. There is an external javascript file that tries to attach some events to my control. Like onclick event is added at runtime to the button.  To do so I use

```
var save = document.getElementById("btnExecute");
```

This control is being called from aspx page where I have attached the JS file. The page won't work, I read articles that it will work if I change the code to something like

```
var save = document.getElementById("<%= btnExecute.ClientID %>");
```

but it only works if the JS is within the aspx file. How to make this work for a custom control. What all steps do I need to follow to get the ID on external JS to work?

Tried Ajax81's solution: Code added

```
namespace MyCompositeControl
{
    public class MyGrid : CompositeControl
    {
        public string ButtonClientID
        {
            get { return btnExecute.ClientID; }
            set { }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            #region Execute Button
            btnExecute.ID = "btnExecute";
            btnExecute.Text = "Execute"; 
            btnExecute.Click += new EventHandler(_button_Click);
            Controls.Add(btnExecute);
            #endregion
    }
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            string jsResourceName = "MyCompositeControl.Scripts.ControlScriptLibrary.js";
            ClientScriptManager cs = this.Page.ClientScript;
            cs.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(this,GetType()), jsResourceName);
        }
}
```

The button is added dynamically as you can see in above code.

ControlScriptLibrary.js

```
  function attachEvents()
   {   
       //var save = document.getElementById("btnExecute");
       var save = document.getElementById("<%=MyGrid.ButtonClientID%>");
       if(save!=null)
       { 
        save.onclick = onSaveAction;
       }
   }
```

Edited: Still it returns null. Can it be that, the JS runs first and the control is not yet there? But this works if I pass the control id like this:

```
function MyController(executeButtonID, onSaveEventHandler)
{
    function attachEvents()
    {   
        //var save = document.getElementById("btnExecute");
        var save = document.getElementById(executeButtonID);
        if(save!=null)
        { 
            save.onclick = onSaveAction;
        }
    }
}
```

In my control's RenderContent method I have the following javascript code:

```
var myController = new MyController(this.btnExecute.ClientID, onSaveEventHandler);
```

This approach will kill if I have more buttons on the control and need some event handling in JS. Ajax81's solution is nice but it is not working for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, when controls are nested in in a form, the name of the controls take on the names of their parents too. For example, an object with the name "ComboBox1" may end up like "ctl00_content_ctl00_ComboBox1" by the time the HTML is output. If you need to refer to the button by its id at browser run-time, then you can inspect the generated HTML code and see what the final name of the button is, then use that in your JS. Be aware though that if the names of any of the buttons parent objects change, then the name of the button may change. As such, this is not a great solution, especially when you may have many of these controls on a page.

There are some JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery and Prototype that provide tools to allow you to more easily find objects in the DOM and attach events.

Comment: Thanks jwatts! Will check the suggested keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for the custom control that returns the client id of the button you need to address in your javascript.

Your code would end up looking something like this:

Inside your Custom Control's Code Behind:

```
public string SaveButtonID
{
   get { return SaveButton.ClientID }
   set {/*nothing*/;}
}
```

In your JavaScript

```
var save = document.getElementById('<%=MyCustomControl.SaveButtonID%>");
```

**EDIT**
Fixed typo in javascript.

Comment: Ajaz81, I have added the code in my original post. Please let me know if you see something wrong..

Comment: ajax81, I corrected the typo but still getting null. I have added the code above and also how the JS is called. Also, put the code how I was able to make it work (though, I like your way but not sure why it didn't work). Appreciate your help.